# Sync Javascript; without a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an app that works in most browsers. Unfortunately, with Internet Explorer 10 on Windows Phone 8, I'm very limited to what I can change. There are a few functions that don't work in WP IE10 - but I want to fix these by hijacking the functions, as opposed to rewriting any code.

```
var valueNeeded =  myFunction("settings")

// This function cannot have another param without me having to change lots of code
myFunction = function (field) {
    db.values('tblStorage', null, 10).done(function (results) {
        return (results[i].value);
    });
}
```

The problem I have is the database call isn't blocking/synchronous and so the return doesn't work. Normally I'd add a callback into the param, but as I want ONE codebase for all browsers, I can't really do that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't have expected this to work in any browser. The fact that `.done()` is asynchronous means that the `return` statement should never actually return from `myFunction`. It returns from the anonymous function passed to `done` though, which doesn't help.

Comment: What you may call an [irrelevant explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16222944/1), I would call important context. Consider this in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous functions require the whole callstack to be asynchronous.

I would rewrite your code to this:

```
myFunction("settings").done(function (value) {
    console.log("value", value);
});

myFunction = function (field) {
    // v-- added return here                 v-- then here, so we return another promise (so we can call .done())
    return db.values('tblStorage', null, 10).then(function (results) {
        return (results[i].value);
    });
}
```

So what does `myFunction` return? It returns a promise. The promise that, when it is resolved, it will have the value you requested.

To be more exact: `myFunction` returns the value of `db.values(/**/).then()`, which is a promise. `db.values(/**/)` also returns a promise. You can stack promises and chain them together to get a kind of asynchronous pipe-and-filter.

If you unchain the functions you'd get something like this:

```
myFunction = function (field) {
    var value_promise = db.values('tblStorage', null, 10);
    var filtered_value_promise = value_promise.then(function (results) {
        return (results[i].value);
    });
    return filtered_value_promise;
}
```